# Getting Crystal to properly embed TT fonts in a PDF

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, truetype

Has anyone run into problems getting Crystal XI to embed fonts when displaying reports via the web (served by RAS) and then exporting to PDF?  We have a barcode font that we use in a few reports, and it worked fine via the web viewer and when exporting to PDF.  When we moved our reporting server from a 2000 box to a 2003 box, the font is no longer exported.  It does  display properly in the html viewer, but when you export it to PDF to print, the PDF doesn't contain the font.  The True Type font is installed on the new server, with scandalously lenient permissions, and the font is installed on all the client machines.  Is there no way to start Crystal in some sort of "debug" mode where it will emit info on what it is doing?

(Edited to specify that it is only when exporting to PDF through a page served by RAS that the font is not embedded)

Comment: Does the font work correctly in applications on the new server? Can you use it in an app like Word or Excel?

Comment: yup. i  can even use it fine in Crystal itself, on the new server.  If I export a pdf from the crystal GUI, the barcode font shows up fine.  It's only when RAS is doing the serving/generating that the font stops being included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far I've come across some info that doesn't help me but might help others with similar symptoms:

One issue that can arise is that Crystal won't embed fonts that have DRM on them.  See [this](http://www.derwok.de/downloads/ttfpatch/) utility to remove DRM if need be.  Microsoft also has a [utility](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/TrueTypeProperty21.mspx) to tell you more than you ever wanted to know about your true type fonts, including their "embeddable" status.  Sadly, my fonts are already embeddable so this did not help me.

EDIT:  FOUND SOLUTION!
The solution [here](https://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1059355&tstart=0) worked for me.  The relevant part was this:

> On the Windows 2003 PC open Control
>   Panel, and double click on Regional
>   and Language Options. Click on the
>   Language Tab and check on Install
>   Fonts for complex scripts.... Now
>   click on the Advanced tab and in
>   Default user account settings check on
>   apply all settings....

Comment: Thank you for the link to the Microsoft site! Very useful in finding out why exporting to PDF (through Crystal API) keeps giving me "Font is not allowed to be embedded in document."

Comment: We've got the same problem but for Windows Server 2008 we do not have the option for 'Install Fonts for Complex Scripts'.  Does anyone know where we can find the same setting for 2008?

Comment: @JoshWeatherly I have same issue with Windows 2008/Windows 7 did you find the solution.

Comment: The link seems to be wrong, there is no such part on it.

Comment: I've used the suggested 'ttfpatch' to change the font restriction property, I set it from type 2 to 0. This allows me to embed the font in PDF

Answer (score 6):

On our Windows Server 2012 R2 - only a reboot required after installing our (DRM-appropriate) font. That is with runtime 13_0_15.

Why you still have to reboot after installing a font is a question for the ages.

Answer (score 5):

For the folks stuck with this problem on Windows 2008, I got barcodes working after I did the following:

- Install the Crystal Runtime.
- Open the fonts folder and select "Font Settings." Make sure the "Hide fonts based on language settings" option is not checked.
- Make sure you have a 3 of 9 barcode font installed on the server and its "Font Embeddability" is "Installable". Also make sure the file is not blocked.
- Set your "Load User Profile" setting under the App Pool Advanced Settings to True.

After after doing the above and rebooting, my barcodes started to work.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Server 2008 supposedly already has fonts for complex scripts enabled according to the article [here](http://www.daicing.com/manchu/index.php?page=complex-script-support).

The option "Advanced tab and in Default user account settings check on apply all settings" setting is similar in Server 2008 but you can select Default User And and / or System accounts.

This solution worked on Server 2003 and we are testing it on Server 2008.  Note that on Server 2003 we had to perform a complete system restart in order for the changes to take affect.