# Report not using correct font when run from web

Tags: crystal-reports

My report uses the *LetterGothic* family font, which displays correctly locally. But when I execute the report from the web (exporting to PDF) the font changes. How can I correct this?

I am using the Crystal Reports package that comes with Visual Studio 2005, and DB: Sql Server.

Comment: Some font types are not fully supported between the two. Are you using a TTF version of LetterGothic?

Comment: Yes, i am using .ttf

Comment: If I were you I'd try switching to a similar font, such as Lucida Console, which is more likely to be recognized across the systems. That might be less work than getting it to actually recognize the font.

Comment: I can't change the font, it's requirement. Is there any solution on this?
Thanks,

Comment: If you absolutely have to use that font, it's going to be an uphill battle. You might try here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1234897/1464444